# Как в родительском компоненте получить доступ к параметру из стейта потомка?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Схематичный пример- имеем 2 класса:

```
var Child = React.createClass({
  getInitialState:  { 
      objects: {} 
  },
  render: function() { 
      return (
       <div value={this.state.objects}></div>
      ); 
  },
});

var Parent = React.createClass({

  render: function() { 
      return (
       <Child/>
      ); 
  },
});
```

в Parent нужно осуществить отправку данных. Отправить надо object,который находится в Child. Один из вариантов таков:

```
var Child = React.createClass({

      render: function() { 
          return (
           <div value={this.props.objects}></div>
          ); 
      },
    });

    var Parent = React.createClass({
      getInitialState:  { 
          objects: {} 
      },

      render: function() { 
          return (
           <Child objects={this.state.objects}/>
          ); 
      },
    });
```

То есть мы из предка передаем чайлду параметр objects и методами чайлда можем его менять. Возник вопрос можно ли как-то без этих плясок с прообросами  параметров из предка получить доступ к стейту чайлда, чтобы вытащить оттуда какие-то данные?(без применения концепций flux\redux) Если да, то как это можно сделать?

Comment: можно через ref. Это - в общем случае костыль которым не надо злоупотреблять. Можно вынести состояние в родителя, это в общем самое верное. Можно устроить как вы выражаетесь "пляски с пробросом параметров из предка". Это - нормально. В любом случае это сигнал из разряда "остановись и подумай о зонах ответственности"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

используейте

> [ref](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

```
class AutoFocusTextInput extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.textInput);
    }

    render() {
       return (
           <CustomTextInput
               ref={(input) => { this.textInput = input; }} />
       );
    }
}
```